Visual Studio MSBuild Error MSB8066: Custom build
I have a Visual Studio solution with a project that generate a cpp and a hpp file.
An other project have to compile these generated files, so I add the cpp file as a "Custom Build" target and the hpp file is "Excluded From Build" (I put it in the solution just to be able to view it).
The program who generate the files works fine and can only exit with 0 as return value, but I have the following error when the second project :
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(254,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for '..\sources\ASM\generated\ASM_x64.cpp' exited with code -1.

I also have this warning some times:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(254,5): warning MSB8017: A circular dependency has been detected while executing custom build commands for item "..\sources\ASM\generated\ASM_x64.cpp". This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.

The generator project it correctly build before everything else and the files are correctly generated.
Here are the "Custom Build" settings of the cpp file:

EDIT: The compilation works fine if the files were already generated and up to date (inputs and code generator not modified). So if I launch the solution compilation a second time it works.
What I am missing?

I assume f-asm_nasm_db_to_code.exe is your own internal custom tool. Is it built by another project in the solution? If yes, is the f-asm_nasm_db_to_code.exe project a dependency of the project with the custom build step?

Yes exactly that is why f-asm_nasm_db_to_code.exe is built before the project that have the custom build step. And the build output show that the logs of the generation of the cpp and hpp files.

Could you see  detailed  error with information about the problem  in the  build output or build log ? Please try to run f-asm_nasm_db_to_code.exe separately to check for any problems.

From looking at your warning message,A circular dependency has been detected while executing xxx and the hpp file is "Excluded From Build",but the compiler will compile the cpp file, the cpp will use the hpp.You use .exe to compile the hpp, then the cpp will be compiled twice.
First of all,  make sure that there are only declarations in your hpp and no definitions, and put all the definitions in the cpp.If you  wants to compile both files yourself, try to Excluded both them from Build.

Hi @XavierBigand, Could you share your steps  and sample to reproduce the issue to help us better understand this scenario?

I solved the circular dependency by renaming ("ASM_x64_CustomBuild") the item that have the custom build. But my main issue that the custom build exit with error code -1 remains, and I don't understand because it should be 0 (the only value my program can return)

Ok, I found the solution by moving the "return 0;" in my generator program.
My generator outputs on stdout few messages with the "error" word. It seems that MSBuild parse stdout to try to detect errors.
I have these messages to help me to debug not handled cases in my generator.
This is really confusing because I saw nowhere in the documentation that MSBuild have this behavior. And it is also why I used stdout instead of stderr.
More info on this issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSBuild:-error:-output-of-custom-build/10554390?sort=newest
